# Inhomogeneous pde in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I tried solving this problem by splitting to a homogeneous solution and a private solution($u=u_h+u_p$). after trying to solve i found that $u_h = 0$ but I am struggling to find the particular solution.

is my homogeneous solution correct?, and how do I find the particular solution?

> `$$\frac{∂^2 u}{∂r^2}  +\frac{1} {r}   \frac{∂u}{∂r} +\frac{1} {r^2}    \frac{∂^2 u}  {∂\theta^2}  =r^2 \sin\theta$$

$$0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}     
$$
$$  0<r<1
$$

$$u(r,\theta=0)=u_{\theta}\left(r,\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0  
$$

$$   u(r=1,θ)=0
$$

`

Comment: You have to separate variables.

Comment: I used seperation of variables for the homogeneus solution but i don't know how to find the private solution

Comment: The inhomogeneous term $r^2\sin\theta$ is separated. So you have to redo everything you did for the homogeneous solution, but taking that term into account. Sit down and think carefully about this, don't rush.

Answer (score 3):

The point of using a homogeneous solution and a particular solution is that you can take a particular solution $u_p$ that does **not** necessarily satisfy all the boundary conditions, then add a solution $u_h$ of the homogeneous equation so the sum $u_h + u_p$ satisfies the boundary conditions.  So $u_h = 0$, which does satisfy the boundary conditions, is not going to be correct unless you happen to find a $u_p$ that already satisfies the boundary conditions (in which case you didn't need $u_h$ in the first place).

In this case there is a particular solution that is a polynomial in $r$ times $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. Can you please explain what is the technique for making an initial guess or direct me to reading material in the subject?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it now.

Can someone please review my solution?

Also, are there any tips on how to guess the particular solution? I feel like I was just lucky in my guess and I don’t fully understand the technique.

$$\frac{∂^2 u}{∂r^2}  +\frac{1} {r}   \frac{∂u}{∂r} +\frac{1} {r^2}    \frac{∂^2 u}  {∂\theta^2}  =r^2 \sin\theta$$

$$0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}     
$$
$$  0<r<1
$$

$$u(r,\theta=0)=u_{\theta}\left(r,\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0  
$$

$$   u(r=1,θ)=0
$$

My solution:

$$ u(r,\theta)=v(r,\theta)+u_p(r,\theta)
$$

Guess:
$$ u_p=Ar^4sin\theta
$$

Find A:
$$12Ar^2sin\theta +4Ar^2sin\theta-Ar^2sing\theta=r^2sin\theta
$$

$$->A=-\frac{1}{15}
$$

Plug $u(r,\theta)=v(r,\theta)-u_p(r,\theta) $into the original PDE:

$$-> \frac{∂^2 v}{∂r^2}  +\frac{1} {r}   \frac{∂v}{∂r} +\frac{1} {r^2}    \frac{∂^2 v}  {∂\theta^2}  =0
$$

$$0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}     
$$
$$  0<r<1
$$

$$v(r,\theta=0)=u(r,\theta=0)-u_p(r,\theta=0)=0
$$
$$v_\theta(r,\theta=\frac{\pi}{2})=u_{\theta}\left(r,\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-u_{p\theta}(r,\theta=\frac{\pi}{2})=0
$$

$$   v(r=1,\theta)=u(r=1,θ)—u_{p\theta}(r=1\theta)=-\frac{sin\theta}{15}
$$

Separation of variables:

$$v(r,\theta)=R(r)T(\theta)
$$
$$-\frac{R”+R’/r}{R}=\frac{T”}{T}=-\lambda^2
$$

$$T”+\lambda^2T=0
$$

$$
T(\theta)=c_1sin(\lambda\theta)+c_2cos(\lambda\theta)
$$

$$T(\theta=0)=0 ->c_2=0
$$
$$T(\theta=\frac{\pi}{2})=c_1\lambda cos(\frac{\pi}{2}\lambda)=0 ->\lambda=2k, k=0,1,2…
$$

$$
T_k(\theta)=sin(2k\theta)
$$

$$v(r,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty R_k(r)sin(2k\theta)
$$

$$R”+\frac{1}{r}R’-\frac{4k^2}{r^2}R=0 -> R(r)=A_{1k}r^{2k}+A_{2k}r^{-2k},r=0  $$
$$ -> A_{2k}=0 
$$

$$v(r,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A_{1k}r^{2k}sin(2k\theta)
$$

$$v(r=1,\theta) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty A_{1k}1^{2k}sin(2k\theta)
$$

For k=0.5:
$$ A_{1,0.5}=-\frac{1}{15}
$$

$$->v(r,\theta)= -\frac{1}{15}rsin\theta
$$

Final solution:
$$->u(r,\theta)= -\frac{1}{15}rsin\theta+ \frac{1}{15}r^4sin\theta
$$